# LightningChart Js -- Maintain setInterval on zoom out event fired on zooming out by mouse rectangle

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I have multiple y-axis and each one has specific setInterval. Here, YAxisArr is an array of all y-axis.

```
 for (i = 0; i < this.yAxisArr.length; i++) {
  if (this.traces[i].enableAutoScaling) {
    dy.fit(false, true);
  } else {
    dy.setInverval(
      this.traces[i].displayProperties.yRange.min,
      this.traces[i].displayProperties.yRange.max, false, true
    );
  }
}
```

On zoom out, I need axis to be zoomed out to the preconfigured values.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event listener to the `onScaleChange` event of your Y axis. In the event you can then check if the axis start or end values are out of the range for the wanted maximum and minimum values. If the values are out of range, then you can set a new interval that is limited to be in the wanted bounds.

```js
chart.forEachAxisY(axis => {
    axis.onScaleChange((start, end) => {
        let newYMin = start
        let newYMax = end
        let updateInterval = false
        if (start < yMin) {
            newYMin = yMin
            updateInterval = true
        }
        if (end > yMax) {
            newYMax = yMax
            updateInterval = true
        }
        if (updateInterval) {
            axis.setInterval(newYMin, newYMax, false, true)
        }
    })
})
```

You can see a working example below.

```js
// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
  lightningChart,
  DataPatterns,
  Themes
} = lcjs

// Import data-generator from 'xydata'-library.
const {
  createProgressiveTraceGenerator
} = xydata

// Create a XY Chart.
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
  // theme: Themes.dark
  disableAnimations: true
})

// Create progressive line series.
const series = chart.addLineSeries({
  dataPattern: DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive
})

// Generate traced points stream using 'xydata'-library.
createProgressiveTraceGenerator()
  .setNumberOfPoints(1000)
  .generate()
  .toPromise()
  .then(data => {
    series.add(data)
  })


const yMin = 0
const yMax = 10

series.axisX.setInterval(0, 1000, false, true)
series.axisY.setInterval(yMin, yMax, false, true)

// Attach listener to all Y axes
chart.forEachAxisY(axis => {
  axis.onScaleChange((start, end) => {
    let newYMin = start
    let newYMax = end
    let updateInterval = false
    if (start < yMin) {
      newYMin = yMin
      updateInterval = true
    }
    if (end > yMax) {
      newYMax = yMax
      updateInterval = true
    }
    if (updateInterval) {
      axis.setInterval(newYMin, newYMax, false, true)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@2.2.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/xydata@1.4.0/dist/xydata.iife.js"></script>
```